# Modal pop-up only works on one image:

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I have an XSLT template which populates a list of thumbnail images, and I want to create a modal popup for each image in a similar way.

```
<xsl:template name="Gallery-View">
    <div class="gallery-images">
      <!--<ul class="hoverbox">-->
      <xsl:for-each select="//Gallery/Images[@folderpath = 'thumb/']">
        <xsl:variable name="path" select="@filename"/>
        <xsl:variable name="title" select="@title"/>
        <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
        <img id="myImg" src="Images/Gallery/thumb/{$path}" alt="{$title}"/>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

          <!-- The Close Button -->
          <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'"><i class="pe-7s-close"></i></span>

          <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
          <img class="modal-content" src="Images/Gallery/full/{$path}" alt="{$title}" id="img01"/>

          <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
          <div id="caption">
            <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script>
<!--// Get the modal-->
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

<!--// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption-->
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";

    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

<!-- Get the <span> element that closes the modal-->
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

<!--// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal-->
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

The problem I'm having is that the modal popup only works on the first image, and if I click on any of the other images I don't even get a console error to tell me where I'm going wrong, just nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need an additional variable since image id cannot be the same for every thumbnail. If you will look at the generated HTML, my guess is that each image will have the same id = **myImg**. So your script is working only for the first image that it encounters with id **myImg**.

Each thumbnail to be clicked needs to have a different id.

You are correct when you say that there is no console error. Javascript doesn't throw any error when multiple HTML elements are assigned the same id because it doesn't need to.